# Spring 4.2 Rest-Service With Hibernate 4 or 5 Example

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest

I am just starting to get into Spring and want to know if there are any example projects that expand on creating a rest service. I completed the rest-service tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and looked at a few others, but now have no clue how to incorporate hibernate into the mix.

As you may know, Spring 4.2 uses the new @RestController annotation which converts a model into JSON. All I am really looking for is an example which stays true to the tutorial I did plus a connection to hibernate, 1 database table, a model, service, and DAO. I don't need any html/jsp pages, so I don't think I need to go down the MVC route, but I could be wrong.

My thought is that I should be able to from the Controller do something like:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController 
{
     @RequestMapping("/things")
     public List<Thing> getThings() 
     {
         ThingService service = new ThingService();
         return service.getThings();
     }
}
```

Where ThingService would call the dao, and the dao to the database.

Can anyone help? Linking to a good tutorial which does this, or taking the time to make me a super small example project would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an easy way to implement your entities as a rest service or to call the dao in your controller and do some business logic.

First I suggest you to use `Spring-Boot`. With Spring-Boot you are very fast in developing Spring applications. You are able to use the full stack of Spring and additional features. I think Spring-boot is exactly what you need.

For your Dao-Rest implementation is `Spring-Data-Rest` the implementation you need. But first look up `Spring-Data` for the initial informations.

Here is an example of [Spring-Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) and [here a particular one for Spring-Data-Rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/).

To start learning Spring using Spring-boot here is the [starter](https://start.spring.io/) if you dont use `STS` IDE. More about Spring-boot you can lookup [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/08/spring-restful-web-services.html

This example would be helpful. Even though version is not Spring 4.2 but this example of Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 sufficient to satisfy your requirement. The versions can be modified in pom.xml and used.

http://www.benchresources.net/resteasy-jax-rs-web-service-integrating-with-spring-mvc-and-hibernate-orm-framework/

another example with 3.2 spring framework.